# Set child grandparent relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've built a web app (PHP/MySQL) for people to predict soccer games.

- For each entry in the `leagues` table, there are many entries in the `matches` table.
- For each entry in the `matches` table, there are many entries in the `predictions` table.

Should I explicitly set a relationship from the `predictions` table to the `leagues` table? In other words, should I add a `league_id` column to the `predictions` table?

**PRO**

Easier queries, less tables to be read in some cases. Example query to look for someones predictions from a certain league with the relationship:

```
SELECT * FROM predictions p
WHERE p.league_id:league_id AND p.user_id=:user_id
```

Without the relationship:

```
SELECT * FROM predictions p
INNER JOIN matches m ON m.match_id=p.match_id AND m.league_id=:league_id
WHERE p.user_id=:user_id
```

**CON**

It's data that's already there, so it's duplicate data (makes the database bigger).

Comment: No need to set the relationship explicitly.

Comment: Having a bigger database is the least of your issues with redundant data. Redundancy is bad for data integrity as it violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and [SSOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) principles. Unless you have a proven need to optimize query performance, I wouldn't consider keeping a redundant column.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I feel sorry that I can not mark this as the correct answer. You are correct, some research learned me that there is no need for optimization if it isn't required (yet). That's basically what you just said in your last sentence :)

Answer (score 0):

A correct normallizzazion of the database is expected that duplicates are avoided above all is to avoid the use of redundant data to avoid relations. You shoul theh withou doubt prefer the second query Theproposed and the related schema

```
SELECT * FROM predictions p
INNER JOIN matches m ON m.match_id=p.match_id AND m.league_id=:league_id
WHERE p.user_id=:user_id
```